# Linq object properties disappear after serialization

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, json.net

I'm trying to understand the included code snippets behavior, it doesn't work as I'd expect. Here is what I'm doing:

1. Serialize a LINQ object to JSON
2. Deserialize the JSON at (1) back in its initial type
3. Validate that each property are still in the Object
4. I serialize the object from (2) back to JSON
5. Print the json from (4) and visually inspect it

My issue is that at (5), any LINQ entity that is a property of the main LINQ object is gone, even tho it was still there when on validation at (3). All my LINQ classes are LINQ to SQL. I am using Newtons JSON.Net library. I tried the same type of logic with non-linq object and the defect seen at (5) doesn't occur.

```
var infoId = Guid.NewGuid();
var alertId = Guid.NewGuid();

var info = new Info();
info.InfoId = infoId;

var alert = new Alert();
alert.AlertId = alertId;
alert.Infos.Add(info);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alert);
Debug.WriteLine(json); //All looking good, nothing missing

var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Alert>(json);
Assert.AreEqual(alertId, deserializedObject.AlertId); //Assert is valid
Assert.AreEqual(infoId, deserializedObject.Infos[0].InfoId); //Assert is valid

var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializedObject);
Debug.WriteLine(json2); //Infos is gone
```

**Update:**

I have done some debbugging, and in the Serialization of deserializedObject

```
var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializedObject);
```

I see the following when reaching the Info Serialization step (next code snipped):

1. this.serializing is true
2. this._Infos.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues is false
3. The get return null is called. (get returns the null value)
4. If I put a breakpoint, and put my cursor on the return this._Infos I actually see the object that It should return ...

   ```
   [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="Alert_Info", Storage="_Infos", ThisKey="AlertId", OtherKey="AlertId")]
   [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order=15, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
   public EntitySet<Info> Infos
   {
       get
       {
           if ((this.serializing  && (this._Infos.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues == false)))
           {
               return null;
           }
           return this._Infos;
       }
       set
       {
           this._Infos.Assign(value);
       }
   }
   ```

**Update:** 
This leads me to believe that I might need to find a way to modify the default value of HasLoadedOrAssignedValues when it is being deserialized from Newtons Json.Net.

I also found a dirty fix, which I don't really like that seems to be working:

```
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EasAlert>(json);
var list = new List<EasInfo>();
deserializedObject.EasInfos.SetSource(list); //<--- Fix, the Info will show up in json2
Assert.AreEqual(alertId, deserializedObject.AlertId);
Assert.AreEqual(infoId, deserializedObject.EasInfos[0].InfoId);
```

Comment: Can you give us more information on how your classes are constructed?

Comment: Can you see the all Informations at Debug.WriteLine(json); ?

Comment: I would use a List for Infos instead of an Array, because it will be mor simple to know what doesn't work at Infos.

Comment: It looks like Infos is a list already, can't call Add() on an array and Infos[0] is just grabbing first item from list

Comment: Can you please include model definitions for Info and Alert?

Comment: The model is a LINQ to SQL model, its really big. I tried the code in another project and the issue wasn't there. It seem's like my coworker implemented an extendsion method that could potentially be behind this issue.

Comment: hi guiomie please view my Question. i have problem with data conversion  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549044/how-to-convert-json-to-local-database-class-property

Comment: constructor. add new list for infos.
public class Alert{
 public Guid AlertId{get;set;}
 public List<Info> Infos {get;set;}

 public Alert() {
  Infos = new List<Info>();
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

I was trying Microsoft's [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and it worked fine. Code and output can be found below.

Could it be a bug in Newton's?

```
void Main()
{
    var infoId = Guid.NewGuid();
    var alertId = Guid.NewGuid();

    var info = new Info();
    info.InfoId = infoId;

    var alert = new Alert();
    alert.AlertId = alertId;
    alert.Infos.Add(info);

    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    var json = jss.Serialize(alert); //JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alert);
    Debug.WriteLine(json); //All looking good, nothing missing

    var deserializedObject = jss.Deserialize<Alert>(json); //JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Alert>(json);
    (alertId == deserializedObject.AlertId).Dump(); //Assert is valid
    (infoId == deserializedObject.Infos[0].InfoId).Dump(); //Assert is valid

    var json2 = jss.Serialize(deserializedObject); //JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializedObject);
    Debug.WriteLine(json2); //Infos is gone - NOT GONE!
}

public class Alert
{
    public Guid AlertId { get; set; }
    public List<Info> Infos { get; set; }

    public Alert()
    {
        Infos = new List<Info>();
    }
}

public class Info
{
    public Guid InfoId { get; set; }
}
```

**Output**:

{"AlertId":"0340e855-065c-4ac7-868e-5999fa4b7862","Infos":[{"InfoId":"31e269a1-4354-423d-84bc-62f6dc06b10f"}]}

True

True

{"AlertId":"0340e855-065c-4ac7-868e-5999fa4b7862","Infos":[{"InfoId":"31e269a1-4354-423d-84bc-62f6dc06b10f"}]}

Comment: To reproduce my error you must use a Linq to Sql Object. With that linq to Sql object you would need to create a new EntitySet<Info>, add your Info object to the set, and then call SetSource(alert) to that EntitySet. The issue will then arise.

Answer (score 0):

check Alert class (**constructor**)

```
public class Alert{
    public Guid AlertId{get;set;}
    public List<Info> Infos {get;set;}

    public Alert() {
        Infos = new List<Info>();
    }
}
```

looks like you are missing List init
[image]

even with EntitySet
[image]