# how to convert json to local database class property

Tags: c#, linq, serialization, windows-phone-8

i have a problem with convert json value to local database class problem 
it works fine if i am use list<> in place of EntitySet

This is my Class properties

when i am converting the below class from  the code

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var data = await client.GetStringAsync("http://demo.com/wk/lg/initimeiNumber=911115000013916&tz=Asia/Kolkata");
Info_Entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Info>(data);
```

it giving Error :

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1[ViewModel.Result]' because the
>   type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To
>   fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])
>   or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g.
>   not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array
>   or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'result.taskarray', line 3,
>   position 17.

```
        [Table]
public class Detail
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    private EntityRef<DetailInfo> _DetailInfo;
    [Association(Storage = "_DetailInfo", ThisKey = "id", OtherKey = "Did", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public DetailInfo DetailInfo
    {
        get { return _DetailInfo.Entity; }
        set
        {
            _DetailInfo.Entity = value;
        }
    }
}

[Table]
public class DetailInfo
{     
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int Did   {  get;     set;  }
    [Column]
    public string phoneno { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string address { get; set; }

    private EntityRef<Info> _info;
    [Association(Storage = "_info", ThisKey = "Did", OtherKey = "Id", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public Info Info
    {
        get { return _info.Entity; }
        set { _info.Entity = value;}
    }

    private EntitySet<Detail> _Detail;
    [Association(Storage = "_Detail", OtherKey = "id", ThisKey = "Did")]
    public EntitySet<Detail> Detail
    {
        get { return this. _Detail; }
        set { this._Detail.Assign(value); }
    }
    public DetailInfo()
    {
        _Detail = new EntitySet<Detail>(
            new Action<Detail>(this.attach_ToDo),
            new Action<Detail>(this.detach_ToDo)
            );
    }


    private void attach_ToDo(Detail Dinfo)
    {
              Dinfo.DetailInfo = this;
    }

    // Called during a remove operation
    private void detach_ToDo(Detail Dinfo)
    {       
        Dinfo.DetailInfo = this;
    }

}

[Table]
public class Info
{

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    private EntitySet<DetailInfo> _DetailInfo;
    [Association(Storage = "_DetailInfo", OtherKey = "Did", ThisKey = "Id")]
    public EntitySet<DetailInfo> DetailInfo
    {
        get { return this._DetailInfo; }
        set { this._DetailInfo.Assign(value); }
    }
    public Info()
    {
        _DetailInfo = new EntitySet<DetailInfo>(
            new Action<DetailInfo>(this.attach_ToDo),
            new Action<DetailInfo>(this.detach_ToDo)
            );
    }
       private void attach_ToDo(DetailInfo Dinfo)
    {
         Dinfo.Info = this;
    }

        private void detach_ToDo(DetailInfo Dinfo)
    {
          Dinfo.Info = null;
    }
}
```

If We uses the Normal List<> it works very Efficently but we can't create mapping with the list

Json Output

```
"result":{
"taskarray":[
{
"lon":79.0630932,
"status":1,
"expdate":1.39054962e12,
"date":"1390463355000",
"clientname":"pranit",
"id":1336,
"csoId":"we1141",
"title":"New Mobile",
"customercontact":"9595588794",
"address":"Dharampeth , Nagpur",
"priority":0,
"description":"none",
"comment":"none",
"note":"none",
"lat":21.1389989
},
{
"lon":79.0743915,
"status":1,
"expdate":1.39046334e12,
"date":"1390463446000",
"clientname":"bb",
"id":1337,
"csoId":"asdf",
"title":"xyz",
"customercontact":"9595588794",
"address":"Sadar, Nagpur",
"priority":2,
"description":"none",
"comment":"none",
"note":"none",
"lat":21.1632626
}
]
},
"status":"success",
"loccheckincom":"",
"code":"200"
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what variable data look like.

Comment: can you show us the json.

Comment: @guiomie, i have put json format

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing an array for deserialization (as the exception is saying). You are passing an object with an array in it, but not an actual array. You need to pass the taskarray property of your json object.

Also, your Info class doesn't match with the json you are receiving from the server.

Comment: i have avoid this, using sqlite please see my Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604644/how-to-get-data-in-the-class-format-with-the-linq/