# how to get data in the class format with the Linq

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8

how can i get the data as my class design

```
public class Fsr
{
    public string formId { get; set; }
    public string formName { get; set; }
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int fId { get; set; }
    public int resultId { get; set; }
}

public class Taskarray 
{        
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int taskId  {get ;set;}   
    public int resultId { get; set; }
}

public class  Result
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int resultId {get; set;}
    public List<Taskarray> taskarray { get; set; }
    public List<Fsr> fsr { get; set; }
    public int rootId { get; set; }

}
```

I am using the below code to get
db is sqliteconntion string;

```
 var data1 = (from e in db.Table<Result>()
              from f in db.Table<Fsr>() where f.resultId == e.resultId 
              from t in db.Table<Taskarray>() where t.resultId == e.resultId 
              select new
              {
                  e,
                  e.taskarray=t,
                  e.fsr=f
              }).ToList();
```

please tell how i get this

Answer (score 1):

Update : as query not reutrning list you can just use specific type without array

```
 select new Tuple<Result, Taskarray, Fsr >
      (
           e,
           t,
           f
       );
```

---

You can make use of tuple if you dont want to create new class fro mapping

```
 select new Tuple<Result, List<Taskarray>, List<Fsr> >
      (
           e,
           t.ToList<Taskarray>(),
           f.ToList<Fsr>()
       );
```

Find linq example at [Tuple Type in C#4.0](http://pranayamr.blogspot.no/2012/12/tuple-type-in-c40.html)

---

you can try like this , you can create new class which handle the data coming

```
select new Myobject 
{
      e= e,
      taskarray =t,
      fsr =f
}
```

Comment: `Result` seemed to be a class mapped to a table, You can't project to entities used with table mapping.

Comment: You should create a new class instead of `Result` and project the results to that class, My point is, your current answer won't help OP since `Result` is mapped to the DB Entity

Comment: Thanks-- conversion error occur Cannot implicitly convert type 'ViewModel.Fsr' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ViewModel.Fsr>'

Comment: @RehanParvez your query denormalizes the data so your f will hold only one fsr how ever your model expects a list. instead of having three froms you need to have the second from where you assign fsr

Comment: @Pranay i want data in list only

Comment: @Habib your recommended tuples giving Error

Comment: @RehanParvez, I didn't recommend using `Tuple`

Comment: @RehanParvez its not Habib recommendation its my option to you

Comment: @Habib ,@Pranay ,i have unable to convert this type to  list

Comment: @Pranay, i have , There is no option to convert to ' .ToList() ' but ToString()

Comment: @RehanParvez = i guess there is no need to use list type you can check my update might work for you

Comment: @PranayRana , it's required becoz i have to get json output in this classes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46990/discussion-between-rehan-parvez-and-pranay-rana)